# TypeError: an integer is required pymysql python

Tags: python, pymysql

I have a database with the following structure

```
 CREATE TABLE cdrdataTest(
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   acctid int(11) NOT NULL,
   session_time int(11) NOT NULL,
   revenue_time int(11) NOT NULL,
   expense_time int(11) NOT NULL,
   start_time datetime NOT NULL,
   revenue_increment int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ;
```

Bellow is my query that is returning and error when I attempt to inser data into a Mysql database using the following code:

```
 conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', 
    db='cdrmonitoringdata')
 cur = conn.cursor()
 for lst in data:
     q = "INSERT INTO cdrdataTest(acctid, session_time, 
   revenue_time,expense_time,start_time,revenue_increment) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, 
   %d,%d,%d )" %
  (int(lst[0]),int(lst[1]),int(lst[2]),int(lst[3]),datetime.datetime(lst[4]),int(lst[5]))
```

error is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mang123/PycharmProjects/readData/readDataFile.py", line 50, in <module>
    insertDataIntoDatabase(data)
  File "C:/Users/Mang123/PycharmProjects/readData/readDataFile.py", line 9, in insertDataIntoDatabase
    q = "INSERT INTO cdrdataTest(acctid, session_time, revenue_time,expense_time,start_time,revenue_increment) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d,%d,%d )" %(int(lst[0]),int(lst[1]),int(lst[2]),int(lst[3]),datetime.datetime(lst[4]),int(lst[5]))
  TypeError: an integer is required

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Don't use string interpolation. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: which error? provide traceback

Comment: One of those is a datetime and not an int

Comment: Even after using the datatime placeholder. still get the error.Integer required

Comment: Show us the sample of `data` and `lst` that is causing the error

Comment: I have a csv separated by a tab ;197280 20 20 20 May 28 2016  2:03:04:630AM 1

Comment: add it to question

Comment: is `'May'` a full name of month or all months names are abbreviated like `'Jan'`, `'Feb'`?

Comment: what does `2:03:04:630AM` mean? hours : minutes : seconds : milliseconds AM/PM?

Comment: also why `2:03:04...` and not `02:03:04...`? (it will cause problems due `datetime` object parsing)

Comment: Check what [\[Python\]: `datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) expects in its constructor. I'm afraid, you'll need to do a bit of parsing the _csv_ date string before passing it to `datetime`. I think `print(lst[4])` wouldn't output what you'd expect.